# Is there a way to access FormBuilder Validators in an Angular directive?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular2-formbuilder, angular-validator

I've been trying to create a custom form validation directive in Angular 8 and I was wondering if it's possible to access the FormBuilder Validators attributes, such as, Required/minLength/maxLength inside my directive.

At the moment I'm handling the min/max values of an input by manually setting the min/max attributes on the HTML input

```
// form.component.html
<form
  customFormValidation // my directive
  class="form"
  [formGroup]="userForm"
  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="input-label">Username</label>
  <input
   type="text"
   minlength="5"
   maxlength="10"
   formControlName="username"
   name="username"
   class="form-control"/>
   ...
</form>

// form.component.ts
ngOnInit() {
this.userForm = this.fb.group({
  username: [
    "",
    [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(5),
      Validators.maxLength(10)
    ]
  ]
});
}

// customFormValidation.directive.ts
...
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) {}
@HostListener("submit", ["$event"])
onSubmit(e) {
e.preventDefault();
this.isSumbited = true;
for (const formInput of e.currentTarget.elements) {
  // For the simplicity of the example just logging the 
  minLength value of each input in the form 
  console.log(formInput.value.minLength); 
}
}
```

As seen above I'm handling the input min/max length by accessing the attributes provided in html but what I really want is to access the min/max from the FormBuilder Validators.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you want to access username error field inside directive?

Comment: Hey @Chellappanவ, I'm trying to access the min/max values of the input according to the FormBuilder and not the minlength/maxlength of the input in the html.

Comment: I dont know if you can inject in the constructor `@Optional() private control:NgControl` and ask about this.control.errors?.minLength, this.control.errors?.maxLength...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why want to create directive for custom validator?
You can learn how to create custom validator for FormGroup here:
https://angular.io/guide/form-validation (Search “Custom validators” word in page)

Comment: Hey @Péter, the custom validations seen in the tutorial you provided require to manually handle the errors in the html. What I'm doing in my directive is to append an error class under the invalid input using jquery, rather than manually adding error handling divs under each input.

Comment: Then lastly, I recommend ng-bootstrap-formvalidation (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-bootstrap-form-validation), if you're using bootstrap. This module automatic add error in your form input, if it has validators and has error. If you not pleased with it, then we will create your directive